# Please Suggest on Following JPA Query Issue

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Please Help to understand how can i write JPA query for this query of MySQL

```
select car_xid from t_booking where from_date between '06/23/2019' and 
'06/24/2019' 
or to_date between '06/23/2019' and '06/24/2019'  or from_date <  
'06/23/2019' or to_date > '06/24/2019'
```

In MySQL this query return car_xid as 1;

I have Booking bean which is mapped to t_booking table in MySQL DB
and Cars table which is mapped to t_cars in MySQL DB

cars bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="m_cars")
public class Cars {

public Cars() {
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="car_pid")
private int carPid;

@Column(name="car_number")
private String carNumer;

@Column(name="car_name")
private String carName;

@Column(name="car_type")
private String carType;

@Column(name="passenger_number")
private int paxNumbers;

@Column(name="available_from")  
private Date availableFrom;

@Column(name="available_to")
private Date availableTo;

@Column(name="rates")
private float ratesPeHour;

@Column(name="deposite")
private float deposite;

@Column(name="is_active")
private char isActive;

@Column(name="from_city")
private String fromCity;

@Column(name="to_city")
private String toCity;

@Column(name="img_url")
private String imgUrl;
}
```

Booking Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_booking")
public class Booking {

public Booking() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="booking_pid")
private int bookingPid;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_xid")
private User user; 

@Column(name="from_city")
private String fromCity;

@Column(name="to_City")
private String toCity;

@Column(name="from_date")
private Date fromDate;

@Column(name="to_date")
private Date toDate;

@Column(name="car_number")
private String carNumber;

@Column(name="deposite")
private float deposite;

@Column(name="passenger_number")
private int paxNumber;

@Column(name="from_loc")
private String fromLoc;

@Column(name="to_loc")
private String toLoc;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="car_xid")
private Cars cars;

@Column(name="transaction_id")
private String transactionId;

@Column(name="total_amount")
private float totalAmount;

}
```

I have tried following JPA Query

```
public interface BookingRepo extends JpaRepository<Booking, Integer>{

    @Query("select b.cars.carPid from Booking b,Cars car where b.fromDate 
    between ?1 and ?2 or b.toDate between ?3 and ?4 or b.fromDate < ?5 and 
    b.toDate > ?6")
    List<Integer> getBookedCarId(Date fromDate,Date toDate,Date from,Date 
    to,Date frmDate,Date tDate);    
}
```

This return null but in actual is should return 1.

Actual result= JPA Query returning null.

expected result= should return car_xid as 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. As you can see you don't need Cars in the where clause:Create the object for Booking Table

```
@Query("select b.cars.carPid from Booking b where b.fromDate between ?1 and ?2 or b.toDate between ?3 and ?4 or b.fromDate < ?5 and b.toDate > ?6")
List<Integer> getBookedCarId(Date fromDate, Date toDate, Date from, Date to, Date frmDate, Date tDate);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding , but this is also not working, currently I am using native query for temporary but i dont want to use native query i want to use jpql.